# UNITY - Attack Hit Combo Code Error. Help needed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's something wrong with my code. When I press the assigned keycode "Z", the CurrentState does not change to 1 and proceed with the whole combo. I tried putting a debug.log and found that the box collider does activate on pressing Z but the number does not increment by 1. Can anyone please help me out? Here's the code.

public class Fighter : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Collider[] attackhitboxes;
public Animator art;
public int CurrentState = 0;
bool activateTimertoreset = false;
public float currentcombotimer;
float origTimer = 50f;
private void Start()
{
    art = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    origTimer = currentcombotimer;
}
void Update()
{
    art.SetInteger("currentstate", CurrentState);
    NewComboSystem();
    ResetComboState(activateTimertoreset);

}

void ResetComboState(bool resettimer)
{
    if(resettimer)
    {
        currentcombotimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(currentcombotimer <= 0)
        {
            CurrentState = 0;
            activateTimertoreset = false;
            currentcombotimer = origTimer;
        }
    }
}
    private void LaunchAttack(Collider col)
{
    Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapBox(col.bounds.center, col.bounds.extents, col.transform.rotation, LayerMask.GetMask("Hitbox"));
    foreach(Collider c in cols)
    {
        if(c.transform.parent.parent == transform)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

void NewComboSystem()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        activateTimertoreset = true;
        CurrentState++;
        if (CurrentState == 1)
        {
            LaunchAttack(attackhitboxes[0]); 
        }

        if (CurrentState == 2)
        {
            LaunchAttack(attackhitboxes[0]);
        }

        if (CurrentState >= 3)
        {
            LaunchAttack(attackhitboxes[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your if (input.keydown) in the update function and have it call your attack. With the way you have it I believe it's calling your attack function many times a second because update runs every frame. Also try debugging the value of currentstate  .

Edit:
Are you assigning currentcombotimer a value in the editor since it's public? In the script it has no starting value. In the start function you assign it to the origTimer. If this value is zero then you have zero combo time.

Comment: This is **not** the problem at-all since `Input.GetKeyDown` is in the `NewComboSystem()` function which is called 100% from the `Update()` function.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem like the problem. I still went ahead and tried it, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions of what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you assigning currentcombotimer a value in the editor since it's public? In the script it has no starting value. In the start function you assign it to the origTimer. If this value is zero then you have zero combo time.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out and you helped me figure out the next part. For some very odd reason, putting NewComboSystem(); after the resettimer thingy in the Update started to increment the value of currenstate. After I did that I was stuck because the value would increment for 0 seconds. I came here and saw you talk about currentcombotimer and went ahead and fixed it. Everything is fine now and it works like a charm. Thank you so much. I would have floundered around my code like a sucker trying to find what's wrong if it weren't for you.

Comment: That is great news.